# Is there a way to recover Pokeballs that miss?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can you recover Pokeballs that miss when trying to catch Pokemon?

Comment: The lost pokeballs usually roll all the way to one of the nearest pokestops. ;)

Comment: NOTE: Lots of downvoted answers on my post...please site sources that may be able to back up your answers. A lot of people are saying that this is possible but not providing any proof. Thanks.

Comment: @ChaseC [sources](http://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/How_to_Throw_a_Poke_Ball) don't prove anything. I just wish people would actually try something that they heard about before spreading it.

Comment: Also see this related question: [Why can't you just pick up your balls?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281360/why-cant-you-just-pick-up-your-balls), which is looking for a canonic explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, every throw regardless of if it misses, hits and breaks out, or hits and captures will use 1 of which ever Pokeball you're using.

Answer (score 11):

Every time you throw a Pokeball, it is subtracted from your inventory and you will *not* get it back, no matter what.

Tapping a Pokeball does not recover it. Instead, it just despawns it and allows the next throw to happen quicker.

Pokeballs are common enough that losing a few won't harm you at all, fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any mention of any way to do so. I presume they expect you to continually restock PokéBalls by visiting PokéStops and spinning the picture - I've collected a lot of Pokémon (thus have thrown a lot of PokéBalls) and have never gone below 100 PokéBalls available (you often get 3 when interacting with a PokéStop).

Comment: It depends on how active you are + how many PokeStops are in your area. For example, there is exactly one PokeStop between my work and my home, so I get a max of 6 PokeBalls a day if I stop there before and after work. I'm just a casual player so I don't care that much, but if I really wanted to I could go downtown and collect a lot more every day as well.

Answer (score -2):

It works for me on great balls but I haven't tried it on anything else. I also had the ar off.  If you recover it, the ball glows and disappears from the battle field.  I believe there was also an animation at the bottom of the screen but I only caught it out of the corner of my eye so I didn't see what it was.  I know it worked because I encountered a Pokemon having only 2 great ball left.  My first throw missed; I taped it as it was rolling and it glowed and vanished.  I caught the Pokemon with the second great ball.  When I finished I checked my bag again and low and behold I still had 1 great ball.  So I know for sure that it works with great balls.

Comment: Nope, this still doesn't work